# Does Mysqli support MAX in a query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get the last date from a table. So I can show the last added or changed item:

```
$qry = " 
        Select
            MAX(changedate)
        FROM
            producten   
        ";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($qry);             
    $stmt->error;
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $up = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();

$main .='Last update '.$up['changedate'];
```

But I receive this error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: changedate in /home/jcslnl/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/michael/paginas/home.php on line 22

Is this because MAX is not longer supported? Or should I continue to search for the error?

It could also be that I did something wrong in the table, it's the firsttime i used     timestamp i.s.o. unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is ***yes, mysqli supports MAX***. However, you need to alias the column, since you aren't actually selecting the *column* `changedate`, but the result of a function which selects the value of `changedate`. In which case `SELECT MAX(changedate) as changedate` provides you with the desired result.

You can also use `var_dump($up);` to see this more clearly in your result.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions will work in mysql, different to the sql standard. to access the value of MAX(changedate) from php, you have to alias it: like this

```
    Select
        MAX(`changedate`) as cngdate
    FROM
        your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

print_r($up)

Why guess is that it is named something different.  So just name it in your query

```
 Select max(changedate) as maxdate
```

And then use $up['maxdate'] in your output.

Answer (score 1):

add `$stmt->bind_result($changedate);` after the execute statement. i.e.

```
$qry = " 
        Select
            MAX(changedate)
        FROM
            producten   
        ";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($qry);             
    $stmt->error;
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($changedate);
    $stmt->close();

$main .='Last update '.$changedate;
```

Answer (score 1):

The column result will actually be `MAX(changedate)`, i.e. `$up['MAX(changedate)']`.
However to make it more readable you should use an alias for you selection

```
Select
    MAX(changedate) as changedate
FROM
    producten
```

and use the same `$up['changedate']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an alias for a result of MAX function,

```
SELECT MAX(changedate) AS maxdate
FROM producten
```